# How to create new visual studio solution with same name of an existing directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a new visual studio solution (.sln) and want it to place in an existing directory structure.
For example:
**Existing Directory Structure:**

```
ParentDirectory
              Sub.Directory1
              Sub.Directory2
```

I wanted to create a VisualStudio solution with name **Sub.Directory1** and place it parallel to Sub.Directory1 folder i.e. as a child of ParentDirectory.

Creating a new solution with the requried name was not possible since VisualStudio always create a directory for new solutions (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c1579334-2b06-4c51-a8d1-7e3443b7e843/uncheck-create-directory-for-solution-for-new-blank-solution?forum=vssetup).
So I created new solution inside Sub.Directory1 folder and now trying to move it to parent directory by using **SaveAs** menu option in visual studio and pointing it to **ParentDirectory**.
But everytime I click Save button, VisualStudio goes into Sub.Directory1 folder.

*(Note: I am using Visual studio 2015 (version 14.xx.xx) latest)*

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You can move the file by hand.

Comment: Yes, SLaks. That can be done, but then the existing projects inside the solutions loose there reference. For a new blank solution, manual moving by hand is good. I did added some projects in my solution earlier, so I had to re-reference them after moving. But it works then... Thanks for help